# SwiftUI '(String) -> Image' is not convertible to '(String, Bundle?) -> Image'

Tags: swiftui

I am getting an error when calling an image:

'(String) -> Image' is not convertible to '(String, Bundle?) -> Image'\

This error show on the line Image(specie.imageName)

This is the whole page code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ForefootView : View {

 @State var iconOpacity: Double = 0.5

let specie: Species

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {

        ZStack () {
            Image("Busanga")
                .resizable()

            VStack (spacing: 10) {

                Image(specie.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(15)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)

                ZStack() {
                    Image(specie.trackSizerImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .opacity(iconOpacity)

                    Image(specie.frontTrackImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }

                HStack {
                    Image(specie.trackSizerImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment:     .topLeading)
                        .opacity(0.2)

                    Slider(value: $iconOpacity, from: 0.0, through: 1.0)

                    Image(specie.trackSizerImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .topTrailing)
                    }
                    .padding(20)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text((specie.fullName) + " " + "FOREFOOT".localized), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: NotesView(species: specie)) {
        Text("Notes").color(.white)
        .font(.custom("Marker Felt", size: 15))
        .shadow(color:.black, radius:1, x:1, y:1)
        })
    }
}
}

#if DEBUG
struct ForefootView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ForefootView(specie: speciesData[0])
}
}
#endif
```

The image name Image(specie.imageName) is used on another page and is fine, so apparently the euro is elsewhere. Help pinpointing possible areas of concern would be appreciated.

Comment: Only looking at the snippet isn't enough to guess your issue. Include the whole View struct.

Comment: The error messages tend to be in random places so either comment out lines of code one by one until you get a meaningful message or post some more code.

Comment: This is the code for the whole page:

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes and the error seems to have gone away, after I chased it all around the page.

```
Text("Notes").color(.white)
```

changes to:

```
Text("Notes").foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

and

```
Slider(value: $iconOpacity, from: 0.0, through: 1.0)
```

changes to:

```
Slider(value: $iconOpacity, in:0...1.0)
```